# how to show UIActionSheet on top of the UIAlertView in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I want to display UIActionSheet on top of the UIAlertView. But according to the below code, it will be hidden from UIAlertView. (See below screenshot )
[image]

First I show the Customised UIAlertView and when user tap Units, then display the UIActionSheet. But it is hidden from UIAlertView. Below is my code set.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (actionSheet.tag == 2) {
        return;
    }

    if (actionSheet.tag == 1 && (int)buttonIndex == 4) {

        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 60)]; 

        UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,100,25)];
        label1.text = @"Dimensions:";
        [v addSubview:label1];

        UITextField *textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,0,60,25)];
        textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField1.placeholder = @"Width";
        textField1.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
        [textField1 setValue:[UIFont fontWithName: @"San Francisco" size:12] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.font"];
        textField1.delegate = self;
        [v addSubview:textField1];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(172,0,25,25)];
        label.text = @"X";
        [v addSubview:label];


        UITextField *textField3 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195,0,60,25)];
        textField3.placeholder = @"Height";
        textField3.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField3.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
        [textField3 setValue:[UIFont fontWithName: @"San Francisco" size:12] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.font"];
        textField3.delegate = self;
        [v addSubview:textField3];


        UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,30,50,25)];
        label2.text = @"Units:";
        [v addSubview:label2];

        UITextField *textField4 = [[ReadOnlyTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,30,155,25)]; //145
        textField4.placeholder = @"-- Select an Unit --";
        textField4.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField4.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
        [textField4 setValue:[UIFont fontWithName: @"San Francisco" size:12] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.font"];

        [textField4 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectUnit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        textField4.delegate = self;
        [v addSubview:textField4];


        av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Dimensions" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Download", nil];
        [av setValue:v  forKey:@"accessoryView"];
        [av show];
    }

-(void)selectUnit:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select an option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    actionSheet.tag = 2;

    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Pixels"];
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Inches"];
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Centimetres"];
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Millimetres"];
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; //[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view

}
```

So how can I display UIACtionSheet on top of the customised UIAlertView????

Comment: Can you explain exact flow of your code ? I think first you called UIActionSheet then response for UIActionsheet is UIAlertView and on UIAlertView action you want to show new UIActionSheet.

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre First I open UIActionSheet and then select an option. when select an option, it will be opened customised UIAlertView. After that when I select customised textfield on UIAlertView (unit field), again open the UIActionSheet. This UIActionSheet is hidden from the previous UIAlerView (see attached image).

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView or ActionSheet have been deprecated. You should really use UIAlertController instead. Then, you can add textfields,buttons as UIActions and each action has completionHandler that makes it easy to implement a method to each object. For example:

```
 UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Test" message:@"Please Enter your name " preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Person Name ";
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField.secureTextEntry = NO;

    }];
    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Yes"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {
                                    //Handle the ENTER button 
                                   // how to Display the name in the label

                                }];
    UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"No"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                   //Handle no button. 
                               }];

    // adding the object to the box
    [alert addAction:yesButton];
    [alert addAction:noButton];

    // present the box
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: for the iPad and when using the UIActionSheet you will still need to create the popover code here.. just FYI